# Python completely crashes when I use kmeans clustering from sklearn, and it is not a memory issue. Any suggestions?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, k-means

When I run any code using kmeans clustering from sklearn, my python crashes (e.g., the kernel dies in Jupyter). This is not a memory usage issue and from what I can tell sklearn is up to date (version 1.0.2).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
sns.set_style('white')

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import sklearn
print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))

# Sample data for clustering
data_file = 'cluster_data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data_file,index_col='id')

X = df[['x1','x2']]

# Plotting data for visual inspection of clusters
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10)) # determines the size of the plot area
ax = sns.scatterplot(x='x1', y='x2',data=df,edgecolor='grey',alpha=0.5)

# Kmeans clustering
sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=3, init='random').fit(df)  # This is where the kernel dies
kmeans_centroids            = kmeans.cluster_centers_
kmeans_labels_k3            = kmeans.labels_
```

When running the 'sklearn.cluster.KMeans' I get the message:
'The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.'

Any suggestions?

(Other sklearn packages work e.g., random forests)
Access to data can be found here:
https://github.com/JakeTufts/Health-Data-Science-Msc/blob/Stack-overflow/cluster_data.csv

Comment: It is a problem related to your machine/environment. Your code works well on a colab kernel (if we add the delcaration of `kmeans`). What happens if you select and use the first 5 rows of your dataframe?

Comment: Unfortunately, the exact same problem. The kernel dies.

Comment: How does your environment work with other Scikit-Learn models? Is it specific to this class?

Comment: Yes, it is only the cluster module (e.g., trees and NN work). I have just tried to use another model (SpectralClustering) and this cause the kernel to die to.

Answer (score 1):

Your input data is a Pandas DataFrame, try to use a numpy matrix instead

```
df2 = df.to_numpy()
sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=3, init='random').fit(df2)  # This is where the kernel dies
```

Now it should work, please let me know the results.

Comment: Hmm, I try this but it still dies...

Answer (score 0):

You maybe see a warning message which says about incompatible libraries with tutorial data.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

`export MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU`
This solved that kmeans kills my jupyter kernel.

Ref = https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl/blob/master/multiple_openmp.md#workarounds-for-intel-openmp-and-llvm-openmp-case